# Codeigniter form validation in config depends on another input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter form validation by config (not setting rules manually). What I need, is setting required rule depending on the other field. For example, Imagine we have the following rules:

```
'user' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'user[phone]',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'user[email]',
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'user[foo]',
        //'rules' => 'required'
    )
),
```

`foo` input must be required based on `email` field.

**Note:** It can be done with **callback** function, but it makes it a bit difficult in big applications. Any idea?

Comment: You may write your custom validation with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: @jagad89 I have already implemented js validation by `Angularjs`. This is about server side validation.

Comment: If you using CI 3.x, have a look [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule)

Answer (score 3):

In your `APPPATH.'config/form_validation.php'` file set separated rule arrays

```
$config = array(
    'yes_email' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'user[phone]',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'user[email]',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'user[foo]',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    ),
    'no_email' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'user[phone]',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'user[email]',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'user[foo]',
        )
    ),
);
```

, then in controller use what ever rule set you want. In example

```
if ($this->form_validation->run($rule) == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('myform');
} else {
    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```

Before this check, you should determine what rule you need there with something like:

```
$rule = 'no_email'; // set default value

switch($this->input->post('email')) {
    case false:
        break;
    default:
        $rule = 'yes_email'; // email has been posted / needed by app etc.
}
```

More in [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#creating-sets-of-rules).

Comment: Thanks. But maybe `anonymous` functions are a better solution than this.

Comment: This code is implementing already existing CodeIgniter resources / structures. Callback functions are another way. You can use any way you want.